# Unable to find click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Here is my JQuery Code:

```
$(function () {
$('[id*=clickbtn]').click(function () {
    var url = "WindowPages/EditorControl.aspx?controlName=" + this.name;
            oWnd.setUrl(url);
            oWnd.show();

        });

});
```

Now the problem is, i have 4 to 5 buttons whose id contains 'clickbtn' when i click the any one of them for first time it works well. But it does not works for second click, any help why is this happening?

[EDIT]:

I tried putting the JQuery on page and it worked.. But wnt to know why it does not work on when i put the same on .JS file?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. You can't have 4-5 buttons with the same ID, or things will not work - try using a class instead.

Comment: What is the oWnd object?

Comment: Well I'm guessing it depends greatly on the contents of the event handler, which you have conveniently omitted...
All you have shown us is what you use to target the buttons, but you've also just said that the targeting works fine (works on first click), so why do you think we'd be able to devine from this code what you did inside of oWnd.setUrl?

Comment: IDs are unique but it contains string like 'clickbtn' ids are like Partsclickbtn, Techclickbtn, etc..

Comment: @NathanHoad he doesn't have multiples of the same id. please read farther than the first sentence, or at least cast a glance at the code

Comment: @Sinetheta: oWnd.setUrl doesn't matter in this case, it does not call even if i replace it with alert('somthing'), my question is why it does not call the function..

Comment: @Dhaval, give us a http://jsfiddle.net/ link to the problem.

Comment: @Sinetheta Congratulations on being snarky for no reason. Misreading != not reading.

Comment: @NathanHoad How do you misread both the text AND the code? No, you did what everyone on SO does, race to get the "omg IDs are unique" comment in first.

Comment: I doubt some exception is occurring after first click, because this worked for me : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/98eA9/4/ .

Comment: @Sinetheta well, being that the key point of the selector was an asterisk, and the key word in the sentence was "contains", I misread it by about 8 characters I'd say. So that's how. Also, this is an educational site, try to educate without belittling.

Comment: @NathanHoad you're really intent on digging your way out of this one huh? Do you often find users targeting IDs with $('[id=myId]')? I know I use $('[class=myClass]') ALL THE TIME

Comment: @Sinetheta Well, no, I just don't like your attitude. What if I was just learning jQuery, and in a moment of confidence thought I'd be able to answer the question, wrote what I did, only to get a response like yours? You don't have an attitude fitting for a community where people help each other learn from their mistakes.

Comment: @NathanHoad I'll join you in the spirit of having an incredibly inappropriate comment squabble. Was my response belittling? Perhaps. But I consider it no more harmful to the SO community than lazy unhelpful responses. There are far too many knee-jerk comments of "link or gtfo" or "need source code" or "IDs are unique" when they are not required. They demean the question asker, and they devalue SO as a whole. Your hypothetical is moot; your response wasn't uninformed it was careless. My attitude is unfit for SO? Since this started I've answered 3 question, including the accepted response here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the result of your event handlers depends very much on the content of your event handlers.  If you'd like to share with us the rest of the code we might be able to help. For now the answer is:  **working as intended**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzNUf/1/)

If your clicks only work on the first try, then I can assure you that it is only the missing code which is to blame. Provide the contents of `oWnd.setUrl` and `oWnd.show`  and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your wildcard selector is wrong.  It should be

```
$("[id$=clickbtn]")
```

Comment: then how does it work on the first click? dollar sign is "ends with"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[ID*="Button"]')
```

**OR**

First set **class="btn"** to all buttons you want to do this action then

```
$(function() {
        $('.btn').click(function() {
        var url = "WindowPages/EditorControl.aspx?controlName=" + this.name;
        oWnd.setUrl(url);
        oWnd.show();
        });
    });
```